# pandas data frame transformations for calculating mean & sem & std for ranges of records

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this data frame structure:

```
AU01_r  AU02_r  AU04_r  AU05_r  AU06_r  AU07_r  AU09_r  AU10_r  AU12_r  

AU14_r  AU15_r  AU17_r  AU20_r  AU23_r  AU25_r  AU26_r  AU45_r  Segment
0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1
1   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1
2   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1
3   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1
4   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1
```

where each 7500 records have the same segment, I mean segments holds the following records ranges:
[[1, 7500], [7501, 15000], [15001, 22500], [22501, 30000], [30001, 37500], [37501, 45000], [45001, 52500], [52501, 60000], [60001, 67500], [67501, 75000], [75001, 82626]]

Currently I have a code - using pandas - that calculate the mean for each segment:

```
df_AU_r_2_mean = df_AU_r_2.groupby(['Segment']).mean()


AU01_r  AU02_r  AU04_r  AU05_r  AU06_r  AU07_r  AU09_r  AU10_r  

AU12_r  AU14_r  AU15_r  AU17_r  AU20_r  AU23_r  AU25_r  AU26_r  AU45_r  WD  CF
Segment                                                                         
1   0.192525    0.156520    0.888929    0.049577    0.092363    0.609992    0.039349    0.385985    0.242643    0.395441    0.456475    0.504961    0.253471    0.074785    0.509816    0.307315    0.093600    1   1
2   0.190215    0.155545    1.027495    0.144367    0.121984    0.872449    0.103985    0.582804    0.311179    0.685669    0.358625    0.605624    0.182963    0.187416    0.530021    0.521449    0.158552    1   0
3   0.187849    0.114435    1.028465    0.110275    0.045937    0.755899    0.088371    0.395693    0.128856    0.376444    0.491379    0.528315    0.245704    0.086708    0.483681    0.442268    0.173515    1   0
```

But I need to enhance it, in such a way that I'll be able to calculate mean/sem/std for each one of the AU columns for each 1500 records (to divide each segment into smaller parts).

I wondered if it can be done using pandas data frame transformations?

Comment: please provide a minimal example (input and output as text)

Comment: is it better now?

Comment: no, it is not minimal nor reproducible, how do you compute `0.192525` from only zeros and ones?

Comment: you don't see the whole data, I'm just outputting the head(),  most of the records do have data... it's a huge df! I'm asking about the concept.

Comment: so your example is not minimal ;) (i.e. self sufficient) please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add a new column as an incremental id. This will be used to create your newer and smaller segments.

```
df.insert(0, 'id', range(1, 1 + len(df)))
```

After that create a new column that indicates each 1500 rows.

```
df["new_Segment"] = pd.to_numeric(df.id//1500).shift(fill_value=0).add(1)
```

Now, you can do the calculations based on new segment column.

```
df_AU_r_2_mean = df_AU_r_2.groupby(['new_Segment']).mean()
```

At the end, the dataframe will be:

```
id    A B C Segment new_Segment
1     x x x    1        1
2     x x x    1        1
..
1500  x x x    1        1
1501  x x x    1        2
..
7500  x x x    1        5
7501  x x x    2        6
..
```

For creating new columns with calculations:

```
df["A_mean"] = df["A"].groupby(['new_Segment']).mean()
```

Comment: sounds good, and if I need more than one calculation mean/sem/std, is it possible to have multiple columns for each feature? (without the need for duplication the df for each calculation)

Comment: could you give an example?

Comment: I mean something like in columns: A A_mean A_sem A_std B B_mean B_std .... and so on. The other option is to save these 3 values as a list for each column [mean, sem, std].. what do you think?

Comment: can you add it your answer pls... both options

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can do this by adding a new column based on your calculations. Please dont forget to upvote, if it works.